# ASP Line-breaks - \n?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, line-breaks

I have been searching for a way to insert linebreaks in my code for when I view my source.  I am not looking for `<br />`

Something like the PHP equiv to `\n`

Any ideas on how to do this in ASP? I will be placing this inside a string.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no way to do it inside a string. You will have to append vbCrLf like so:

```
Response.Write "hello" & vbCrLf & "world"
```

If you want to include it in the string, you could do a replace after like so:

```
output = "hello\nworld"
output = Replace(output, "\n", vbCrLf)
Response.Write output
```

Comment: On a side note, in ASP.NET you'll want to use Environment.NewLine instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the **`\n`** method, I have also embedded the HTML tag **`<BR>`** and used:

```
Response.Write "First Line Of Text<br>Second Line Of Text<br>Third line Of Text"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, using `"\n"` didn't work and resulted in `\n` appearing as text on the webpage rather than as a newline in the source code view, however using `chr(10)` did work. Using `CrLf` was not an option for me as that generates a windows line ending (\r\n) and I needed the Linux line ending which is just the linefeed (\n).

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is just print html break line with response function

like this : `Response.Write "<BR>"` you can send any other HTML command as well with this method just watch for Quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using `<br/>` tag like:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

 </head>
<body>
      <%
       dim i
       for i=0 to 10
       response.write(i & "<br/>")
       next 
       %>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the defined const `vbCrLf`, `vbCr` and `vbLf`

```
vbCrLf = char(13) & char(10) 'Same as PHP \r\n
vbCr   = char(13)            'Same as PHP \r
vbLf   = char(10)            'Same as PHP \n
```