# How to output UTF-8 format and newline in mail

Tags: outlook, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to send mail in a particular time with task scheduler on windows.

The output I have in body is not what I expect and does not give a newline.

Is there any way to control the format of the output?

```vb
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="CP65001"%>

Const MSG_RECIPIENT_LIST = "foor@bar.com"
Const MSG_SUBJECT = "力"
Const MSG_BODY = "これをやろう" + vbNewLine + "我々は一緒に大きなものを達成する"

Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkMsg
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olkSes = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName
Set olkMsg = olkApp.CreateItem(0)
With olkMsg
    .To = MSG_RECIPIENT_LIST
    .Subject = MSG_SUBJECT
    .HTMLBody = MSG_BODY
    .Send
End With
olkSes.Logoff
Set olkMsg = Nothing
Set olkSes = Nothing
Set olkApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Is `CP65001` a valid value for `CODEPAGE`? Usually it's `CODEPAGE = "65001"`.

Comment: You control the output using `Response.CodePage` for any dynamic strings you build in the page.

Comment: If you're using `HTMLBody` you will need to convert any line breaks into HTML readable values. `.HTMLBody = Replace(MSG_BODY, vbNewLine, "<br />")` as @K.Davies had suggested. You should also be using [tag:cdonts] to do this instead of [tag:outlook] which requires that it is installed on the web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP classic CDO Email messaging use UTF-8 in textbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061974/asp-classic-cdo-email-messaging-use-utf-8-in-textbody)

Comment: This link will help for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366968/asp-line-breaks-n

Comment: I think you want vbCRLF.

Comment: @Lankymart  Did you really mean cdonts, or were you thinking of cdosys?  :)
https://www.itnota.com/replace-cdonts-with-cdosys-classic-asp-pages/

Comment: @John it’s the same library there’s barely any difference just Microsoft repackaging attempts. I mean CDO, whether it’s CDONTS, CDOSYS or just plain CDO. I honestly don’t care, notice the duplicate and stop thinking you’re clever.